# API VK Загрузка файла в сообщение Node js

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api, formdata, multipart, multipartfile

Пытаюсь прикрепить файл в сообщение беседы.
Необходимо реализовать рассылку отчетности в чат группы раз в период.
На текущий момент никак не могу со своей стороны определить в чем причина, происходит как-будто все успешно - файл прикрепляется, сообщение доходит, но при попытке скачать его из беседы - пишет, что файл не найден.
node js v16.14.2

```
import VkBot from 'node-vk-bot-api';
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';
import fs from 'fs';
const bot = new VkBot("***");
const maindir = process.cwd();
const VKsendFile = (url,fpath,cb)=>{
    const form = new FormData();
    let file = fs.createReadStream(fpath,{encoding: 'utf-8'});//Пробовал и без encoding
    form.append('file', file);
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url,
        headers: form.getHeaders(),
        data: form
    }).then(cb);
}
bot.execute('docs.getMessagesUploadServer', {
    type: "doc",
    peer_id: 2000000000+<Номер чата>
})
.then(response=>{
    VKsendFile(response.upload_url, `${maindir}\\test-file.txt`,res=>{
        console.log(res.data);
        bot.execute('docs.save', {
            file: res.data.file
        })
        .then(r=>{
            bot.execute('messages.send', {
                group_id: <Номер группы>,
                chat_id: <Номер чата>,
                peer_id: 2000000000+<Номер чата>,
                random_id: Math.round(Math.random()*100000),
                attachment: `doc${r.doc.owner_id}_${r.doc.id}`
            }).then(response=>{
                console.log('success');
            });
        })
    })
});
```

подскажите, может я неверно описываю form-data или еще где-то, но на все запросы к ВК - получаю успешные ответы.

Comment: через form.submit тоже не работает

Comment: через простой https.request и и формирование multipart через строку тоже не работат

Comment: Обходное решение - заменить на docs.getWallUploadServer и файл загрузился в файлы группы, но при этом и в беседе его стало можно скачать